# How to upload UIImage from iOS to Azure storage

Tags: objective-c, azure-storage

I try to upload an image to Azure storage through MVC 4 web API. But the server side always return:

> "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."

Below is Objective-C code:

```
- (IBAction)btnUploadReceipt:(id)sender {
    UIImage *img = self.imgReceipt.image;
    NSData *dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    NSString *fff = [dataObj base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
    //NSString *ddd = [self base64EncodeString:imgData];
    //NSString *ddd = [dataObj base64EncodedString];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/upload/UploadAzure",baseUrl]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"Post"];

    NSString *jsonData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FileName=%@&FileData=%@&FolderName=%@&UserName=%@&Point=%@&DateTime=%@&MerchantName=%@&OutletID=%@",fileName,fff,imgFolder,userName,@"3",dateTime,_mName,_mOutletID];

    [request setHTTPBody:[jsonData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             NSString * json =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

             NSLog(@"%@",json);

             if ([json isEqualToString:@"\"True\""]) {
                 NSLog(@"%@",@"Success Add Photo");
                 //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                 //[[self navigationController]popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
             }
             else
             {
                 UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:@"Please Check Internet Setting" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

                 [messageAlert show];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:@"Please Check Internet Setting" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

             [messageAlert show];                 
         }
     }];
}

- (NSString *)base64String2 {
    UIImage *img = self.imgReceipt.image;
    NSData * data = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
}
```

Anyone face this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Azure Storage iOS Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ios)? The [Getting Started documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage/#upload-a-blob-into-a-container) should be able to help with your scenario.